# webpack warnings when running nextjs dev server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, next.js13

getting this warnings when running `npm dev`:

```
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restoring pack from /Users/pdeva/code/monorepo/web/app/.next/cache/webpack/client-development.pack failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasStartTime')
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restoring pack from /Users/pdeva/code/monorepo/web/app/.next/cache/webpack/server-development.pack failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasStartTime')
```

Here is the full output:

```
npm run dev

> app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /Users/pdeva/code/monorepo/web/app/.env.local
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.

info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restoring pack from /Users/pdeva/code/monorepo/web/app/.next/cache/webpack/client-development.pack failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasStartTime')
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restoring pack from /Users/pdeva/code/monorepo/web/app/.next/cache/webpack/server-development.pack failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasStartTime')
event - compiled client and server successfully in 958 ms (246 modules)
wait  - compiling /page (client and server)...
```

the app does work but not sure whats causing the warnings. I tried deleting the `.next` and `node_modules` dir but still continue to see them.

Comment: Technically, they are warnings, hence the `<w>`. Since you're using experimental features, perhaps it is safe to ignore this if it's not causing any problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rm -rf .next/cache will fix the problem

Comment: This cleans the cache and worked for me!

Comment: I deleted the .next folder and worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Aquib here..
This problem is created when your next.js version is not upgraded to the latest one ..
Ex:- Your `next.js` version is 12 and you doing `npm run dev` then this shows..
Try this `npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest` and then try again hopefully it gives correct.

Comment: I don't think upgrading to a new version should be a solution here. If my requirements are for a certain version, then this is not possible.